# Evaluate: $\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{(1+x)\log(x)}\, dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{(1+x)\log(x)}\, dx$$

Wolfram alpha gives an answer of $\log(2/\pi)$, but I have been unable to prove this. Help appreciated.

Comment: the result should be $\frac{2}{\pi}$